# Change style of first item in listview

Tags: android-listview, android

I have a list of items in a listView. I would like to highlight the first item of this listview so that the user knows top item is active. How can I go about doing this?
Something like the image[image]

Comment: Set android:listSelector and android:drawSelectorOnTop in you listview.

Comment: listSelector needs drawable and drawSelectorOnTop is a flag.

Comment: create custom a drawble and use it as background of listview then listview.setselection(int pos).

Answer (score 2):

Try Some like tha:
create custom listview adapter like that and adapter, [Custom adapter for a list of items that have multiple child items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485986/custom-adapter-for-a-list-of-items-that-have-multiple-child-items/23486051#23486051)
then set bg like that:

```
if (position == 0) {
        // define layout here list 1st item
        view.setBackground(R.drawable.bg);
    } else {
        // others
        view.setBackground(R.drawable.bg);
    }
```