# OnClickListener not working in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In my application, I have added one button named as 'add'. If I click that button, I want to perform some another activity. But if I click the button, nothing happens. Can anyone please tell me what is my mistake?

`ListViewAdapter` class:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
     /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {

        Button Add;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView title;
         ViewHolder holder = null;
        ImageView thumb_url;


        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.Add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);



            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        //View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rank);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        thumb_url = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        title.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TITLE));

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.THUMB_URL), thumb_url);
        // Capture ListView item click
        Button Add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        try {
            holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    try {                              

                        //call ur intent here
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);



                        startActivity(in);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    protected Context getApplicationContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    protected void startActivity(Intent in) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

Comment: You write that button click not working, But i have seen that you have not set any thing in onClick  of button.

Answer (score 0):

Set focusable and focusable in touch mode to `FALSE` for other view of your row layout other than button.

Comment: can you please tell me where i want to set

Comment: in your listview_item.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick` listener should be like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                // Write your code here     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you Know how to perform Button onclick()?

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick()` method is empty:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

An empty method obviously doesn't do anything.

You probably wanted to have your unused `onItemClick()` as your `onClick()`.

After that you probably want to replace empty `getApplicationContext()` and `startActivity()` with calls to actual implementations of similarly named methods.

Comment: can you add some example

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated code:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
     /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {

        Button Add;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView title;
         ViewHolder holder = null;
        ImageView thumb_url;


        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();




            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        //View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rank);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        thumb_url = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        Add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        title.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TITLE));

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.THUMB_URL), thumb_url);
        // Capture ListView item click

        try {
            holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    try {                              

                        //call ur intent here
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);



                        startActivity(in);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked Add Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    protected Context getApplicationContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    protected void startActivity(Intent in) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

Comment: In which place your changed if i added this code nothing happended

Comment: now check update answer when you click that show toast "Clicked Add Button"

Comment: can you please tell me in which place your changed with my code

Comment: Follow that answer and create custom adapter like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485986/custom-adapter-for-a-list-of-items-that-have-multiple-child-items/23486051#23486051

Comment: Hi toast message also it's not displaying

Comment: now follow my last comment and create custom adapter like that

Comment: hi toast is displaying

Answer (score 0):

Use This code instead of your `onClick`.

```
holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //call ur intent here
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
        startActivity(in);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked Add Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you code:

```
holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // your code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) method:

```
Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //call ur intent here
       Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
       startActivity(in);
       Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked Add Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, First.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
});
```